# Are there performance issues with CSocket::Send?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, visual-c++, concurrency

**UPDATE 14 June 2011**

A quick update... Most respondents have focused on the dodgy method for handling the queue of messages to be logged however while there is certainly a lack of optimisation there it's certainly not the root of the problem.  We switched the Yield over to a short sleep (yes, the Yield did result in 100% CPU once the system went quiet) however the system still can't keep up with the logging even when it's going nowhere near that sleep.  From what I can see the Send is just not very efficient.  One respondent commented that we should block up the Send() together in to one send and that would seem like the most appropriate solution to the larger underlying issue and that's why I have marked this as the answer to the original question.  I certainly agree the queue model is very flawed though, so thanks for feedback on that and I have up-voted all answers that have contributed to the discussion.

However, this exercise has got us to review *why* we're using the external logging over a socket like we are, and while it may well have made sense previously when the logging server did lots of processing over the log entries... it no longer does any of that and therefore we have opted to remote that entire module and go for a direct-to-file approach via some pre-existing logging framework, this should eliminate the problem entirely as well as remove unnecessary complexity in the system.

Thanks again for all the feedback.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

In our system we have two components important to this problem - one is developed in Visual C++ and the other is Java (don't ask, historic reasons).

The C++ component is the main service and generates log entries.  These log entries are sent via a CSocket::Send out to a Java logging service.

**The problem**

Performance of sending data seems very low.  If we queue on the C++ side then the queue gets backed up progressively on busier systems.

If I hit the Java Logging Server with a simple C# application then I can hammer it way faster then I will ever need to from the C++ tool and it keeps up beautifully.

In the C++ world, the function that adds messages to the queue is:

```
void MyLogger::Log(const CString& buffer)
{
    struct _timeb timebuffer;
    _ftime64_s( &timebuffer );

    CString message;
    message.Format("%d%03d,%04d,%s\r\n", (int)timebuffer.time, (int)timebuffer.millitm, GetCurrentThreadId(), (LPCTSTR)buffer);

    CString* queuedMessage = new CString(message);
    sendMessageQueue.push(queuedMessage);
}
```

The function run in a separate thread that sends to the socket is:

```
void MyLogger::ProcessQueue()
{
    CString* queuedMessage = NULL;
    while(!sendMessageQueue.try_pop(queuedMessage))
    {
        if (!running)
        {
            break;
        }
        Concurrency::Context::Yield();
    }

    if (queuedMessage == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        socket.Send((LPCTSTR)*queuedMessage, queuedMessage->GetLength());
        delete queuedMessage;
    }
}
```

Note that ProcessQueue is run repeatedly by the outer loop thread itself, which excluding a bunch of nonsense preamble:

```
while(parent->running)
{
    try
    {
        logger->ProcessQueue();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
}
```

The queue is:

```
Concurrency::concurrent_queue<CString*> sendMessageQueue;
```

So the effect we're seeing is that the queue is just getting bigger and bigger, log entries are being sent out to the socket but at a much lower rate than they're going in.

Is this a limitation of CSocket::Send that makes it less than useful for us? A mis-use of it? Or an entire red-herring and the problem lies elsewhere?

Your advice is much appreciated.

Kind Regards

Matt Peddlesden

Comment: Try commenting out the Yield().

Comment: If I comment out the yield, the system will spin to 100% CPU.  I would have thought that if there was something in the queue, then the try_pop would return and it wouldn't ever even get to the Yield? Or am I missing something... ?

Comment: you're busy spinning, try_pop doesn't block if there's no item in the queue. with or without the yield() call, the current scheme seems very ineffective. You'll need to somehow block if the queue is empty, and wake up when data is pushed onto the queue. It seems concurrent_queue does not provide that though, so you'll have to make up something yourself, either with condition variable or events.

Comment: Ok i'll take that feedback and we'll look in to it - however, if the system is now largely idle (out of hours), and the log is about 1 hour out of date (about 150mb in memory) - why is it not now able to blast that out very quickly? I'd assume that the situation you describe would mean we get behind during the day but quickly get caught up once the system goes quiet.  As it happens, the system is logging at the same rate it has done all day.  In this case, we're getting something back from try_pop every time and logging it on every cycle of the thread, presumably? or am I missing something?

Comment: What is a 'cycle of the thread'? If this function is being called continualy in some other thread loop, then I would expect this function, and the loop that calls it, to use up 100% CPU when the rest of the system is idle, whether the Yield() is in or not.  Calling Yield() would just schedule this thread back on again immediately because there is nothing else to do.  This is very confusing!

Comment: I think you're missing my point - if you forget normal operation when the system is gettings lots of new log items and lots of log items out the queue and tons of other activity, look at the system now and really the only thread doing anything is this process queue thread.  The queue is loaded to the top, so try_pop always returns something (or will do for a while at any rate), therefore the yield never happens and every time the while loop iterates it should log something.  So this should happen at max speed - it doesn't, even in this quiet state, logging is slow.

Comment: Ok, now the system has gone quiet, yes it's gone to 100% of one core because of the Yield.  So i'll take that feedback and learn from it - thanks :)  I've asked the C++ developer to look at getting a semaphore in there and we'll see how it does.  My gut still tells me there's a problem with CSocket::Send though.

Comment: The pseudo code should be something like:  look for a message. If there is one then send it. Loop back to the start if there are more messages. return to the caller.  If you're getting 100% CPU then the calling thread/process isn't waiting between calls to check for work. If you're polling you should set some reasonable wait time between checks. This will limit your total responsiveness but will eliminate the CPU hogging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you're definitely not looking at the most efficient solution. You should definitely call Send() once. For all messages. Concatenate all the messages in the queue on the user side, send them all at once with Send(), *then* yield.

In addition, this really isn't how you're meant to do it. The PPL contains constructs explicitly intended for asynchronous callbacks- like the `call` object. You should use that instead of hand-rolling your own.

Comment: Ah, so rather than using one Send() per line of log, we could just concatenate them all together in to one big CString and use a single Send()? I like that idea... What about send limitations? Or is this where repeatedly calling Send() until all the bytes are gone is required (as discussed in some of the online examples) ?

Comment: Also, i'm not entirely sure what you mean by PPL - sorry if that's a basic question! Can you expand on that aspect of your answer too?  Many thanks indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could start by using a blocking producer-consumer queue and to get rid of the 'Yield'.  I'm not surprised that messages get blocked up - when one is posted, the logger thread is typically, on a busy system, ready but not running.  This will introduce a lot of avoidable latency before any message on the queue can be processed.  The background thread than has a quantum to try an get rid of all the messages that have accumulated on the queue.  If there are a lot of ready threads on a busy system, it could well be that the thread just does not sufficient time to handle the messages. especially if a lot have built up and the socket.send blocks.

Also, almost competely wasting one CPU core on queue polling cannot be good for overall performance.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: My understanding is that the yield is meaning we aren't using excess CPU - indeed, at this moment on a live server that is currently logging 1 hour+ behind real time, CPU usage is around 0% and I have not seen any abnormal CPU usage than prior to this change all day.  Logs are steadily flowing out to the logging server at the same rate they have all day.  So in this instance, the Yield is never even being reached.  I must admit our intention with this implementation was to try and eliminate all locking - but we could certainly try switching to an implementation that uses a wait/notify.

Comment: Oh!  Hang on.. what calls ProcessQueue, then?  Is there another loop with some signalling you did not show?

Comment: It's in the third section of code in the original question - basically, while running, logger->processqueue.

Comment: OK, so I get 5% for observation <g>

Comment: You may well wish to avoid locking but, given concurrent_queue, there may be locking in there already, (not sure if your c_c implementation is lock-free or not).  As a first try, add a semaphore, initialized to zero.  Signal it after pushing a message onto the queue and, in the thread, wait on it before calling try-wait.

Answer (score 1):

Things here that might be slowing you up:

- **The queue you are using.** I think this is a classic example of premature optimization. There's no reason here to use the Concurrency::concurrent_queue class and not a regular message queue with a blocking pop() method. If I understand correctly, the Concurrency classes use non-blocking algorithms when in this case you do want to block while the queue is empty and release the CPU for other threads to use.
- **The use of new and delete for each message and the inner allocations of the CString class.** You should try and see if recycling the messages and strings (using a pool) will help performance for two reasons: 1. The allocation and deallocation of the messages and string objects. 2. The allocations and deallocations done inside the strings can maybe be avoided if the string class will internally recycle its buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried profiling to see where your application is having trouble? Is it only when logging that there are issues with the sender? Is it CPU bound or blocking?

The only thing I can see is that you don't protect the message queue with any sort of locking so the container state could get weird causing all sorts of unexpected behavior.

Comment: The message queue is a thread safe ConcurrentQueue.  See concurrent_queue.h
System is not CPU bound in any way at all, no.

Comment: Apologies for numerous comments, having wetware trouble using the site! :)  - Not tried profiling yet, i'm sadly not a C++ programmer so this is totally alien territory to me.  The sender is only ever used in this scenario for logging, every other use of sockets that we have on the system is far lower bandwidth so we have not seen any similar issues anywhere else.